# How to retrieve data from response and set in properties using groovy?

Tags: groovy

i have a response after a request with soapui.
in the response i have several element with the same name for example ID
The content of ID is different at many places.

here is the response:

```
{
"assig":[
{
"id":1,
"repId":2,
"enTId":3,
"Type":"Report",
"recipients":[]},

{
"id":2,
"repId":3,
"enTId":4,
"Type":"Report",
"recipients":[]}
```

When i try this:

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue('id',slurperresponse.id.toString() )
```

It sets in property all ID in one line separated by comma like this: [1,2]

How can i separate them in different name in property?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're converting a list to a string

Try

```
slurperresponse.id.eachWithIndex { id, idx ->
    testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue("id${idx+1}", "$id") // or id?.toString()
}
```

Comment: it gives me an error : groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:

Comment: You're going to have to give a bit more info than that... it should tell **which** method is missing?

Comment: the error is: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlTestSuitePro.setPropertyValue() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl, java.lang.Integer) values: [id1, 12137] Possible solutions: setPropertyValue(java.lang.String, java.lang.String), getPropertyValue(java.lang.String)